Javascipt video: Error getting userMedia: DOMException: Could not start video source
I want to write a video messanger on js and I havent video camera on my PC. So I connect my phone(use DroidCam) and permited for my webstie to use DroidCam Source. But in my cosole I see the next error: Error getting userMedia: DOMException: Could not start video source
My useEffect:
 useEffect(() => {
    async function startCapture() {
      try {
        localMediaStream.current = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: {
            width: 1600,
            height: 900,
          },
        });

        addNewClient(LOCAL_VIDEO, () => {
          const localVideoElement = peerMediaElements.current[LOCAL_VIDEO];

          if (localVideoElement) {
            localVideoElement.volume = 0;
            localVideoElement.srcObject = localMediaStream.current;
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error getting userMedia:", error);
        setCameraAvailable(false); // Устанавливаем флаг, если не удалось получить доступ к камере
      }
    }

    startCapture()
      .then(() => socket.emit(ACTIONS.JOIN, { room: roomID }))
      .catch((e) => console.error("Error getting userMedia:", e));

    return () => {
      if (localMediaStream.current) {
        // Добавляем проверку на null
        localMediaStream.current.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
      }

      socket.emit(ACTIONS.LEAVE);
    };
  }, [roomID]);

Maybe someone can help me?
I dont know what I should do
